# How to unload GMSMapView from memory?

Tags: swift, memory-leaks, gmsmapview

I have UIViewController with GMSMapView (connected from storyboard) like this

```
@IBOutlet weak var map: GMSMapView!
```

in

```
override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
        
        self.map.delegate = nil
        self.map.clear()
        self.map.removeFromSuperview()
        self.map = nil
          
    }
```

and also I have

```
deinit {print "DEINIT ME"}
```

Deinit works - I see print message.

I have to load and unload this viewcontroller many times during app works. Dismiss - this is presented view controller.
And each time I use it - in memory adds new GMSMapView.
Ten times I use controller - ten GMSMapView objects will be in memory graph and so this connect with huge memory leak.

How can I unload GMSMapView from memory when I dismiss this viewcontroller?

Answer (score 0):

The code in your `viewDidDisappear` is useless. The map view is already defined as weak, which means it will release from memory when the view controller de-initializes. Check your memory graph if the view controller is still there after you de-initialize it. If the view controller is still there, then some other property in your view controller is holding a strong reference to the view controller, and has nothing to do with the map.
Otherwise this might be a problem in the GMSMap framework.